# Completely unusable software

Tags: 14.04, graphics, xubuntu, display

I'm currently running Xubuntu 14.04 (the same issues were present under Ubuntu 14.04), some of my software is just impossible to navigate and use due to display issues.

Software like Spotify, TortoiseHG, EasyMercurial, etc...  Other software works fine, it's hard to pinpoint what's common about the ones that don't work.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: spotify]

[image: tortoise]

And here are my device driver settings for graphics:
[image: graphics]

I've tried using different display drivers, nothing helps. (Including the Nouveau drivers=

I've made no changes to what ships with Ubuntu/Xubuntu, whenever I restart the system everything is OK, but a few minutes after booting up any of these programs, the display issues come back. Closing the software and reopening it does not help either. I run a 4 monitor setup if it helps in any way.

I've been chasing the issues all over the internet, but don't know what to do any more really!

Comment: "it's hard to pinpoint what's common about the ones that don't work." all seem to be about graphics. "I run a 4 monitor setup if it helps in any way." And when you only use 1 monitor? I would consider filing a bug against `nvidia-graphics-drivers-346 346.96-0ubuntu0.0.1`  ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug ).